# why jquery fadein is working only once?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I've coded my own ModalDialog function, and the popup is working only once. Here's my ModalDialog function:

```
function ModalDialog(button, text, fadeOut) {
    $('.error-notification').remove();
    var x = "#" + button; 
    var $err = $('<div>').addClass('error-notification')
                 .html(text)
                 .css('left', $(x).position().left);
    $(x).after($err);
    $err.fadeIn('slow');
    if (fadeOut == true) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $err.fadeOut()
       }, 3000);
   }
   //$err.delay(0).fadeOut('slow');

}
```

And here is the code that is in the script file that masterpage loads.

```
$(".error-notification").live('click', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function () { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Here is how I am calling the function.

```
ModalDialog('testingAjax', 'h', false);
```

I know the ModalDialog function is being called each time, because I used console.log inside the function at the very last. So why is it showing the popup only once and not second/third/fourth time etc...?

Answer (score 2):

You are removing all previously existing popups:

```
$('.error-notification').remove();
```

It's actually showing them all, but keeping only the last one.
Here's a relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BhU6F/3/

Comment: Indeed, it's working just fine. [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/BhU6F/4/) update fiddle proving it's showing the correct text.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard That is exactly what I wanted to do: show only the last one. Basically, ModalDialog function is being called onclick of a button. So, imagine this: Click the button -> popup. Click the popup -> popup gone. Now when the user clicks the button again, it should popup again, which it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does work. In [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhU6F/4/) click the button - "hello" appears. Click the "hello" and it will vanish. Click the button again and new "hello" will appear.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, you're correct, and I have updated the fiddle to include CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/dZq4d/1/ However, I am still clueless why it's not working for me. To give more details, when the user clicks the button, it submits an Ajax request and onComplete of the Ajax request calls ModalDialog() function. Again, it is indeed being called and everything, based on console.log. Any pointers?

Comment: Post your full code and we'll try to spot what might be wrong. Also, it's possible to use AJAX in jsFiddle, just find free service exposing JSONP interface.